# Handling C Strings In C++11

Tags: c++11, c-strings

I have an abstract base class that can't use STL containers and is limited to POD types:

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase() = default;
    virtual void getName( char*& ) = 0;
}
```

I also derive from this class and have helper functions so I can work with my class internally with STL containers:

```
class Derived : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void getName( char*& );
    virtual void getName( std::string& );
private:
    std::string name;
}
```

And implement them as such:

```
void Derived::getName( char*& name ) // Function signature can't change.
{
    name = (char*)malloc( sizeof( char ) * ( m_name.length() + 1 ) );
    strcpy( name, m_name.c_str() );
}

void Derived::getName( std::string& name )
{
    name = m_name;
}
```

And I'm handling it like this:

```
void functionThatDealsWithAbstract( Base* base )
{
    char* name;
    base->getName( name );
    // Do some stuff with c string
    free( name ); // Been pointed out that if I am freeing in this space, I should malloc in this space as well (because of module boundaries)
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more safe way to handle this with C++11. I don't want accidentally copy/paste and forget that I need to free the pointer. I came up with this:

```
void functionThatDealsWithAbstract( Base* base )
{
    char* namePointer;
    base->getName( namePointer );
    std::shared_ptr<char[]> name( namePointer, std::default_delete<char[]>() );
}
```

Is this a safe way to deal with C strings using C++11 idioms?

Comment: Out of interest, who is responsible for calling `free`?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++? Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: @EdHeal I have an abstract base class and I'm using POD types and not STL containers because I'm working between at the boundary between DLL and application. I have a function `void DerivedClass::getName( std::string& );` that just calls the `char*` version

Comment: @JacobHull: For true rigour you can't rely on the DLL `malloc` being equivalent to the application `free`. You ought to burden the caller with the task of creating a memory buffer, or provide a DLL function to release the memory that it's allocated.

Comment: Can you specify which parts of the code must remain the same and which must change? Can the implementation of `Class::getName` change (even if the interface can't)?

Comment: @Bathsheba The caller of getName would be responsible for freeing. I thought about `std::unique_ptr`, but I think I need to retrieve the pointer to cast to a string. Also thats a great point about `malloc`, thanks

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to better describe what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @Bathsheba Do you think that adding a `getNameLength()` to the abstract base class and have the caller malloc and free the char be appropriate?

Comment: A pair of `getNameLength()` and a `getName()` that fills a preallocated buffer while asserting that it's indeed big enough is definitely appropriate. However, if you want to stick to returning a newly `malloc()`'ed string, which is definitely also a useful interface, you should rename your function to something like `copyName()` or even `makeCopyOfName()` to imply that you are returning a new object that needs to be `free()`'d.